# GeoCoordinateWatcher on different phones

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, gps

I'm using the standard way of using the class and the strange thing is that on some phones it works (Nokia lumia 920, htc, etc) and on some it doesn't (lumia 610, samsung omnia 7w).

```
GeoCoordinateWatcher watcher = new GeoCoordinateWatcher(GeoPositionAccuracy.High);
watcher.MovementThreshold = 0.1;
watcher.StatusChanged += (x, y) =>
{
      MessageBox.Show(y.Status.ToString());
};
watcher.PositionChanged += watcher_PositionChanged;
watcher.Start();
```

What I'm getting here is on all phones the GCW initializes, but I'm getting NoData on Lumia 610 and Samsung.

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this answer will help someone:

Be sure that if your phone doesn't give you a gps reading, to stick in a sim card, so that it can get the location from it. Apparently lumia 610 and samsung omnia 7w don't have a built in gps or something... :)